# Mongoose Nodejs pull element from array by property of property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So here is my mongoose Object:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("626aaff13fa90efda9ea1975"), 
    "username" : "Raxo", 
    "password" : "089a9902261aa3d27218ef8ea5e4885a52cafc7278684978b0953dc6846f07a6", 
    "solved" : [ 
    { 
        "challenge" : { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("627178fd7fff3bdc2ad941e6"), 
            "name" : "Challenge6315 ", 
            "category" : "crypto", 
            "flag" : "Nice try XD", 
            "hints" : [ "Easy Peasy Lemon Squeezy!" ], 
            "points" : 100, 
            "info" : "I am a challenge!", 
            "level" : 0, "solveCount" : 0, 
            "file" : "", 
            "__v" : 0 
        }, 
        "timestamp" : 1651603748444
    }], 
    "score" : 800, 
    "key" : "65b8457a-9c00-4829-8d18-ed2e19cef53", 
    "isAdmin" : true, 
    "teamId" : "62717c6a7b8c337ac509176a", 
    "__v" : 0 
}
```

I am trying to delete the challenge inside the solved array using:

```
        await users.updateMany({
            solved: { $elemMatch: { 'challenge._id': challengeExists._id } }
        }, {
            $inc: { score: -challengeExists.points },
            $pull: {solved: {"challenge._id": challengeExists._id}}
        });
```

It does find the user successfully and remove points from the score but does not successfully pull the challenge, I cant seem to find what I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated

Also weirdly it works in the CLI with:

```
db.users.updateMany({ solved: { $elemMatch: { 'challenge._id': ObjectId("627191c0fcff360116a67528") } } }, { $pull: { solved: { "challenge._id": ObjectId("627191c0fcff360116a67528") } }, $inc: { score: -100 }, })
```

Comment: Also when trying these in the mongo CLI I got positive results, and not in nodejs for some reason.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate, it's just `$pull: {solved: {"challenge._id": challengeExists._id}}`

Comment: @AlexBlex I have tried that which did not work

Comment: Try better https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ww4gTy2jtyL

Comment: Like I said works in the CLI but for some reason does not in nodejs using mongo, which is weird.

Comment: Must be something to do with mongoose or values you are passing from the app. [Enable profiling](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#mongodb-method-db.setProfilingLevel) and check how queries look like on mongodb side.